# Count red pixel values and plot histogram in Python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, image-processing, scikit-image

I have a set of images that are located in 3 separate folders, based on their Type. I want to iterate through every Type and count the red pixel values of every image. I have set a limit for red, being in range from 200 to 256. I want to create histograms for each type and later cluster the histogram and discriminate between the 3 classes. My experience with Python is very limited and I am stuck at how to isolate and count the red pixel values. I have attached my code and the resulting histogram for Type 1, which is a straight line. Could someone help on this?

```python
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os.path
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## take the image, compute sum of all row colors and return the percentage
#iterate through every Type
for t in [1]:

    #load_files
    files = glob.glob(os.path.join("..", "data", "train", "Type_{}".format(t), "*.jpg"))
    no_files = len(files)

    #iterate and read
    for n, file in enumerate(files):
        try:
            image = cv2.imread(file)
            hist = cv2.calcHist([img], [0], None, [56], [200, 256])

            print(file, t, "-files left", no_files - n)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            print(file)

plt.plot(hist)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Why convert `BGR2RGB`? if you care only about red, then why do you do `inRange` on all 3 channels? Why not just grab the red channel (either using `cv2.split` or just numpy indexing) and work with that?

Comment: I tried to do  `image = cv2.imread(file)` `img= cv2.split(image)`, but it returns that _img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar_

Comment: what do you mean by numpy indexing?

Comment: Yes, it's not a numpy array, it's a python list containing one single channel numpy array per original channel (e.g. a BGR image would be split into 3 separate arrays). [Numpy array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: so, in order to get the red channel i should add a line saying `im = img[0, :, :]`?

Comment: Although, i tried that and it says that _list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple_ ..

Comment: Looks like you attempt to index the result of the split, and got the indicies in reverse order. Assuming you start with a BGR image, `image = cv2.imread(file)` then you have two options: a) `red = cv2.split(image)[2]` b) `red = image[:,:,2]`

Comment: Ok, but now it returns _'numpy.uint32' object is not iterable_ for each image file

Comment: Please, update the question to reflect recent code changes, and include the full error message indicating which statement causes the error.

Comment: I updated the code snippet. It doesn't return any errors, but i still get the same straight line in the plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with. I have taken the liberty to refactor and simplify your code a bit.

```
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage import io

root = 'C:\Users\you\imgs'  # Change this appropriately
folders = ['Type_1', 'Type_2', 'Type_3']
extension = '*.bmp'  # Change if necessary
threshold = 150  # Adjust to fit your neeeds

n_bins = 5  # Tune these values to customize the plot
width = 2.
colors = ['cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow']
edges = np.linspace(0, 100, n_bins+1)
centers = .5*(edges[:-1]+ edges[1:])

# This is just a convenience class used to encapsulate data
class img_type(object):
    def __init__(self, folder, color):
        self.folder = folder
        self.percents = []
        self.color = color

lst = [img_type(f, c) for f, c in zip(folders, colors)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for n, obj in enumerate(lst):
    filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(root, obj.folder, extension))

    for fn in filenames:
        img = io.imread(fn)
        red = img[:, :, 0]
        obj.percents.append(100.*np.sum(red >= threshold)/red.size)

    h, _ = np.histogram(obj.percents, bins=edges)
    h = np.float64(h)
    h /= h.sum()
    h *= 100.
    ax.bar(centers + (n - .5*len(lst))*width, h, width, color=obj.color)

ax.legend(folders)
ax.set_xlabel('% of pixels whose red component is >= threshold')
ax.set_ylabel('% of images')
plt.show()
```

[image: multiple bar plot]

Notice that I have I used scikit-image rather than OpenCV to read the images.  If this is not an option for you, insert `import cv2` and change:

```
    img = io.imread(fn)
    red = img[:, :, 0]
```

to:

```
    img = cv2.imread(fn)
    red = img[:, :, 2]
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Tonechas. It works, but I have a few questions, in order to fully understand what you did. Why did you put the threshold at 150? I know i can change it to any other number, but what does it represent? Also, this code compares the distribution of red pixels in every image, depending on their Type. So this is the training process. If I want to test a new image, without knowing its Type, how could I classify it to the correct one, based on its number of red pixels?

Comment: I set the threshold to a moderate value of `150` because in the images I used to perform the tests there are no pixels with high intensity values in the red channel. If I had set the threshold to `220` I would have obtained [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppw8s.png)

Comment: I'll answer the second part of your comment in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44159348/compare-multiple-histograms-in-file-opencv)