# Python: ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1

Tags: python, image-processing, computer-vision, classification, svm

Following [Tonechas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6160119/tonechas) suggestion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44162949/5945369), the code to compute the red channel histogram of a set of images and then classify them to the correct type, is this:

```python
import cv2
import os
import glob
import numpy as np
from skimage import io


root = "C:/Users/joasa/data/train"
folders = ["Type_1", "Type_2", "Type_3"]
extension = "*.jpg"


# skip errors caused by corrupted files

def file_is_valid(filename):
    try:
        io.imread(filename)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def compute_red_histogram(root, folders, extension):
    X = []
    y = []
    for n, imtype in enumerate(folders):
        filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(root, imtype, extension))
        for fn in filter(file_is_valid, filenames):
            print(fn)
            image = io.imread(fn)
            img = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=0.1, fy=0.1, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            red = img[:, :, 0]
            h, _ = np.histogram(red, bins=np.arange(257), normed=True)
            X.append(h)
            y.append(n)
     return np.vstack(X), np.array(y)

X, y = compute_red_histogram(root, folders, extension)

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.5, random_state = 0)

from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_test
clf.predict(X_test)
y_test == clf.predict(X_test)
score = clf.score(X_test, y_test)

prediction = pd.DataFrame(y_test, score, columns=['prediction', 'score']).to_csv('prediction.csv')
```

I get this error:

**ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1**

Can someone help with this? Thanks

Comment: seems like your `y_train` contains only one class. verify that all three classes are represented in `y_train`.

Comment: How can I verify that?

Comment: (1) you can spot the bug in `compute_red_histogram()` or (2) print `(y_train.min(), y_train.max())` and see that it's all zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at you function:

```
def compute_red_histogram(root, folders, extension):
    X = []
    y = []
    for n, imtype in enumerate(folders):
        filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(root, imtype, extension))
        for fn in filter(file_is_valid, filenames):
            print(fn)
            image = io.imread(fn)
            img = cv2.resize(image, None, fx=0.1, fy=0.1, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)
            red = img[:, :, 0]
            h, _ = np.histogram(red, bins=np.arange(257), normed=True)
            X.append(h)
            y.append(n)
        return np.vstack(X), np.array(y) ## <--- this line is not properly indented.
```

You `return` at the end of the first iteration of the `for` loop over `folders`. you need to un-indent this line.

Comment: Thanks. I also want to save my predictions to a .csv file and I have updated the code above to show you what I did. Apart from the class every image belongs to, I want to show the prediction score, but it gives me this error: **TypeError: len() of unsized object**. Do you know why?

Answer (score -1):

I just have the same problem
and I figured out
some times the label or the target is String when ur data is downloaded
try y=y.astype(np.uint8)